# Why does the 'init' method run in two times by the same object?

Tags: objective-c

I know the 'init' method of superclass(Person) can be executed before executing the 'init' method of subclass (Student).But why those two or three 'init'(I guess the 'init' of NSObject can be executed as well) can be executed by the same object(s) of Student?

```
 @interface Person : NSObject
 @end

 @implementation Person
 - (id)init{
 if (self = [super init]) {
 NSLog(@"init--------%@",[self class]);
   }
 return self;
 }
 @end

 @interface Student : Person
 @end

 @implementation Student
 - (id)init{
 if (self = [super init]) {
 NSLog(@"init--------%@",[self class]);
    }
 return self;
 }
 @end


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

 Student *s = [Student alloc];
 Student *ss = [s init];

 return 0;

 }
```

My code's result:

init--------Student

init--------Student

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call a method of your superclass, your class type hasn't changed.  When you `init` the `Student` object, it calls the `init` of `Person`, but it's still a `Student`.

Comment: I see your comment and I don't understand why I init the Student object ,it calls the init of Person ,it;s still a Student .But  I thinking about the override. The 'init' of subclass(Student) overried its superclass(Person)'s 'init' .When I  'init' the Student object  , it calls the init(overrided) of Person and then it calls itself init .I'm not sure it is right or mistake.

Comment: @CJiYI I'm not sure what the problem is, but yes, this is definitely the intended behaviour. In order for a class to be constructed properly, you typically have to call the constructor of the superclass. Since obj-c doesn't have the notion of a constructor, the convention is to use the `init` method family instead, but the idea remains the same.

Comment: Methods are just functions that get a pointer to an instance of a class.  Usually, the instance is a class of the same type, but in the case of subclassing, a superclass's methods may be called with instances of the subclass.  But, it's still just a function call getting a pointer.  Nothing changes what the pointer is pointing to.  Whatever object it is does not, and cannot change, just because you called a method.

Comment: @David Oh！There you go！Thanks！